# PHP string in an array

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation

Write a PHP script to put a string in an array.(3 marks)

Sample strings : "Twinkle, twinkle, little star,\nHow I wonder what you are.\nUp above the world so high,\nLike a diamond in the sky.";

The following is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
<title>my task</title>
 </head>
<body>

<?php
  $str = "Twinkle, twinkle, little star,\nHow I wonder what you are.\nUp  above the world so high,\nLike a diamond in the sky.";
  $arra1 = explode("\n", $str);
  var_dump($arra1);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**output:**

```
 array(4) { [0]=> string(30) "Twinkle, twinkle, little star," [1]=> string(26) "How I wonder what you are." [2]=> string(27) "Up above the world so high," [3]=> string(26) "Like a diamond in the sky." }
```

Please tell me if this is the right code for it or needs modifications based on the expected result?

Comment: what are you asking? - furthermore, SO isn't used to answer your exam question :) also a few tips - indent your code, 4 spaces is the industry-standard. Use single-quotes - they're faster than double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

### PHP explode() Function

The explode() function breaks a string into an array.

**Note:** The "separator" parameter cannot be an empty string.

**Note:** This function is binary-safe.

```
$str = "Twinkle, twinkle, little star,nHow I wonder what you are.nUp  above the world so high,nLike a diamond in the sky.";
$arra1 = explode(",", $str);
var_dump($arra1);
```

> OUTPUT :-

```
array(5) { [0]=> string(7) "Twinkle" [1]=> string(8) " twinkle" [2]=> string(12) " little star" [3]=> string(55) "nHow I wonder what you are.nUp above the world so high" [4]=> string(27) "nLike a diamond in the sky." }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<?php
  $str = "Twinkle, twinkle, little star,\nHow I wonder what you are.\nUp  above the world so high,\nLike a diamond in the sky.";
  $arra1 = explode("\n", $str);
  var_dump($arra1);
?>
```

**output:**

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(30) "Twinkle, twinkle, little star," [1]=> string(26) "How I wonder what you are." [2]=> string(28) "Up above the world so high," [3]=> string(26) "Like a diamond in the sky." }
```

use `\n` , b'coz you use `\n` in string not `<br>`

Answer (score 0):

Your string contains `\n` not `<br />`, so you should use `\n` as delimiter in `explode('delimiter',$string);` instead of `<br />`.

Try this:

```
<?php
  $str = "Twinkle, twinkle, little star,\nHow I wonder what you are.\nUp  above the world so high,\nLike a diamond in the sky.";
  $arra1 = explode("\n", $str);
  var_dump($arra1);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of explode() is as below

**explode('delimiter','string')**

delimiter=> tells where to break the string. and

string=> is the input string to split.

Try this `explode('\r\n', $str);`

Use single quotes for newline `\n` it works.